# Why can you not switch the limits of $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}||\textbf{1}_{A_n}f||_p$?

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Suppose that $\left(X, \mathcal E, \mu\right)$ is $\sigma$-finite. So we have that $X=\bigcup_{n}A_n$ where $\left(A_n\right)_n$ is an increasing sequence of elements $A_n\in \mathcal E$ where $\mu\left(A_n\right)<\infty$.

My question is then, what is the reason for that you can't switch the limit of the following:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}||\textbf{1}_{A_n}f||_p=||f||_\infty$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if $f \equiv 1$ and firstly you take limit as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Do we then have $\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}||\textbf{1}_X||_p$?

Comment: Exactly, and what happens if $\mu(X) = +\infty$ ?

Comment: Is that even possible, $\mu\left(X\right)$ can't be greater than 1. Or is that a wrong statement

Comment: I don't quite understand. How it comes that $\mu(X) \le 1$? You stated that $(X,\mathcal E,\mu)$ is $\sigma-$finite (even with the definition of the latter). What is the problem for example with $(X,\mathcal E,\mu) = ([0,2],\mathcal B([0,2]),\mathcal L)$, where $\mathcal B([0,2])$ are borel sets and $\mathcal L$ is a Lebesgue measure on $[0,2]$. It is $\sigma-$finite (even finite) with $\mu(X) = 2$.

Comment: Okay I understand, I just thought that $\mu\left(X\right)$ was a probability measure